# Eclipse JBoss Tools EL Autocomplete not working with Jakarta API

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jakarta-ee, jboss-tools

I just did fresh install of Eclipse & JBoss Tools but can't get the EL autocomplete to work.  I tracked it down to the use of Jakarta API.  If I use the older JavaEE API, the EL autocomplete works as expected, but nothing is displayed when using the Jakarta API in the pom.

Eclipse Version 2022-12 (4.26.0) using vm: JDK 17.0.4.1

JBoss Tools Version 4.26.0 Final (Installed from Marketplace)

**Example using Jakarta**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

.

```
package test;
import java.io.Serializable;
import jakarta.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Named;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class JakartaNamedObject implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    //getters and setter
    
}
```

[image]

**Example using Javax**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>8.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

.

```
package test;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class JavaxNamedObject implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            
    //getters and setter
    
}
```

[image]

I used the Eclipse installer to install Eclipse 2022-12, with a brand new workspace and then Eclipse Marketplace to install JBoss Tools 4.26.

I guess the question is does EL autocomplete work with Jakarta and if so why is it not working in my fresh new setup?

Comment: I have opened a bug report on your behalf in JBoss Tools Jira project https://issues.redhat.com/browse/JBIDE-28842.

Comment: @jeff Can you  please provide a full example of both projets to reproduce ?

Comment: @sbouchet Is the example code above not enough? Like how much more do you want? Sorry for late reply was on holiday.

Comment: In order to reproduce, can you provide the complete non-working project or a step-by-step ? Providing just the pom.xml, a java snippet and a screenshot of the html file is hard to reproduce. Thanks

Comment: @sbouchet Here is the project:  https://github.com/jrozycki/jakarta-el-auto-eclipse-test

Comment: thank you, i can reproduce and we'll take a look to provide a fix.

Comment: We provided a fix in the latest JBossTools 4.27.0.Final. Please use it when it will be released.

Comment: Awesome! I actually tried a snapshot last week and it seemed to be working.  I will try 4.27.0.Final soon!